# How do I format SharePoint Rest API Results?

Tags: 2013, rest, filter

How do I get my SharePoint Rest API Results to return like so:

Title : FDA Project RioBravo
Module: Primary Training
Roles : Project Manager, Lead Agent

versus the way this returns them like so:

Title : FDA Project RioBravo Module: Primary Training Roles : Project Manager, Lead Agent

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/items?$filter=File_x0020_Name Eq 'FDAAgents'&$top=1",
type: "GET",
headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
cache:false,                
success: function(data){
console.log(data);
var items = [];
$(data.d.results).each(function(){
items.push('<ul id="' + 'listUL' + '">' + 
'<li id="' + 'listLI' + '">' + 
this.Title  +
'</li>' + 
'</ul>');
});
items.push("</div>");
$("#listResult").html(items.join(''))}
});
</script>

<div id="listResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/items?$filter=File_x0020_Name Eq 'FDAAgents'&$top=1",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    cache:false,                
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var html = "<table border='0'>";
        $(data.d.results).each(function(){
            html = html + "<tr><td>" + this.Title + "</td></tr>";
        });
        html += "</table>";
        $("#listResult").html(html)
    }
});
</script>

<div id="listResult"></div>
```

Comment: Amal - Thanks! This worked great. It allowed me to pull the list items I needed and display them accordingly.

Comment: @Bitspider nice to hear it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

You an also try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/items?$filter=File_x0020_Name Eq 'FDAAgents'&$top=1",
type: "GET",
headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
},              
success: function(data){
console.log(data.d.results.length); 
    $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
        var html = "<table border='0'>";
    html = html + "<tr><td>" + item.Title + "</td></tr>";   
});
    html += "</table>";
    $("#listResult").html(html);
},
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
</script>
<div id="listResult"></div>
```